# ListBox Menu in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Howdy,
I want to make a dynamically filled Menu in Windows Phone 7. I thought that a listbox would be the perfect fit for that. However, I cannot get the "selectedValue" once the user interacts with the listbox - hence I cannot give any information to the navigationhandler.

How can I create a ListBox whose Listbox Items are created dynamically and navigate the User on click to the same page but with different parameters e.g.

`\informations.xam?id=2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that long ago I wrote an WP7 application and I used something like this:

```
private void CategoryList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CategoryList.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
    string id = (CategoryList.SelectedItem as DepartmentViewModel).ID;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/CatalogueBrowser/CategoriesPage.xaml?deptId=" + id, UriKind.Relative));
    CategoryList.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Basically, I set my listbox's itemssource to an observable collection of particular view models, then you just access the selected view model object using the SelectedItem property of the listbox.

Comment: and note that the selection gets set back to -1, its an important detail.  (if you don't do it, and you navigate back, clicking the same item will do nothing, since selection didn't "change")

Answer (score 1):

Create a new "Windows Phone Databound Application" and the boilerplate code generated as part of the project will show you how to do this.